# Create models within model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have two models: `Report` and `SinglePage`.
A user can upload a PDF-Report. Every Page of this report gets turned into an image and is saved into its own single_page-instance.

Currently, I am saving the report (in my controller), and if the save is successful, I create the single_pages for this report (also from within the controller).

I don't like this approach, since this kind of logic should be handled within the model itself. Another problem is, that the report gets created, no matter if the single_pages for the report can be created or not. Of course, I could catch in the controller, but I consider this a bad practice.

What I actually want to achieve is this:

1. The user uploads a PDF-Report
2. The report gets split and each single page is turned into an image
3. Each image is saved into its own single_page-instance

   - NOTE: The single_pages are all created within a single method, which returns false, if one or more pages can't be created.
4. Only if all the single_pages get created, the report gets saved.

I tried to override the initialize-method within the Report-Model, but I am not getting this dependency to work. Either the report-model itself has an error, or it gets saved, no matter what's the deal with the single_pages.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks, Mandi

Comment: Have you tried any of the callbacks available, such as `before_create` or `before_save`, on `Report`?

Comment: Oh man, this is almost embarassing :-) 
I have tried this callback way back, but there was another problem, according my method that creates the single_pages;
I retried it now and it works like a charm. If you post this answer appropriate, I'll give you your well earned points ;-)

Comment: How are the single page instances failing to be saved? Is there a validation that fail, or is the process that converts the page into an image failing?

Comment: I have no reputation shame :)

Comment: @Olives: honestly, I have no idea, since a colleague of mine wrote the script that I am invoking in my method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried any of the callbacks available, such as `before_create` or `before_save`, on `Report`?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap all the saves up in a [transaction](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html).

Also, you didn't mention it, but I assume you have a parent-child relationship between Reports and SinglePages?  If so, then if you build (not save) the pages and then save the report, rails will try to save the dependent children and will not save the parent if the children fail to save.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. For now, I am pretty happy with the before_save-callback, even though I have to admit, that both of your solutions seem more Rails-like. I will definitely look into it for future solutions. 
Best regards, Mandi